# Replace images with media queries responsive emails

Tags: outlook, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to code a responsive email, so that when the user's resolution is below 480px we hide big images and replace them with smaller background images. However, it turns out that background images do not show in outlook on mobile nor on desktop. So what would be the method of replacing big images for smaller images in responsive emails?

Thanks!

Comment: Does outlook even respect media queries? I typically end up with a bunch of inline styles to make things look decent in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically your design needs to still "work" with background images missing, if at all possible.

Outlook (by which I mean the desktop application rather than outlook.com, the Hotmail replacement) is pretty much the worst email client when it comes both to supporting all kinds of basic HTML/CSS features - [Campaign Monitor CSS compatibility chart](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) - and more modern stuff like media queries - this is because Outlook 2007, 2010 and even the 2013 version all use the Microsoft Word rendering engine…

There [is a VML-based background image hack](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3363/updated-applying-a-background-image-to-html-email/) but it's pretty horrible and not guaranteed to work - I wouldn't recommend.

Obviously you need to consider the audience of your email campaign, but personally and unless you have a client demanding Outlook support (though you can try and explain the situation) I've rather felt Outlook is what the 'Click here if this email does not appear correctly in your browser' link at the top of your message was made for - I would check the body text is readable in Outlook but frankly not concern yourself with too much else, concentrate on getting it right in the [mobile clients that *do* allow media-queries](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2012/10/responsive-email-support/).